# PHP or MYSQL not recognizing value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php to query from mysql in which either the home_team or away_team column contains a given value. I know that records of such values exist in the DB. But, for some reason either PHP or MySQL is telling me that it's not. My code is as follows.

```
$teams = array("St. Louis",
       "NY Yankees",
       "NY Mets",
       "LA Dodgers",
       "LA Angels");

foreach($teams as $given_team)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM current_season_games WHERE home_team = '".$given_team."' OR away_team = '".$given_team."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_result($query, 0);

    echo "".$count."<br />";
}
```

I know that the $count variable that's being echoed is incorrect. I'm looking at some rows in the DB that fit the conditions specified in the query.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: you cont need the loop, you can use IN()

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758121/how-to-get-the-result-of-a-select-count-query-in-php) for info on similar queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to check:

- is PHP connecting to the same host and database? (This has been a 'DOH!' moment for some developers, when they have multiple databases... one local, and one on a test server.)  Are you sure you are querying the same table?
- try testing a simpler query, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM current_season_games` to see if you can get any non-zero count returned
- try putting the query into a string, and echoing out the string, before you execute it
- is this an InnoDB table, and have the rows you are trying to count been committed? (Did the session adding the rows do a START TRANSACTION, insert the rows, and then not yet commit them? (This is a DOH! moment for some developers that are using multiple environments (e.g. SQLyog and a web server).  (A separate session with transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE READ would not see the uncommitted rows)
- is that column in the database using a case sensitive collation, where the equality comparison in the predicates (WHERE clause) is being handled as case sensitive vs. case insensitive?

None of those may solve your problem, but it's impossible to tell (from here), without a lot more information, what the issue is. But it's a few things you can check.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out to be a mysql collation problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `COUNT(*)`. This won't give you the value of the field.  `COUNT(*)` is usually used to measure how many results are returned.

What you'll want to do is actually select the column name or alternatively, select the entire row that matches the criteria. Something like this -

```
SELECT * FROM current_season_games 
WHERE home_team = '".$given_team."' OR away_team = '".$given_team."'")
```

Comment: Well, when I tried to execute an update query on the rows where the home_team or away_team column was one of the values in the array, it didn't work either.

Comment: Still, $count should be equal to the number of rows that exist in the table where either the home_team or away_team is equal to the $given_team. It's returning 0. It's certainly not 0. It's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In old code that I come across still using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, I'll usually come across the use of the [`mysql_num_rows()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

I would recommend changing your code to something like this -

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM current_season_games WHERE home_team = '".$given_team."' OR away_team = '".$given_team."'")or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Notice that the `mysql_query()` function doesn't return a `$query` as your variable name indicates. It returns a result set that you can then inspect to retrieve that actual data.

Comment: For the record, in the grand scheme of things, I don't even need to know how many rows are returned. Ultimately, I need to perform an update query. But, that doesn't work either because the values in the array aren't showing up as existing in the table. It's weird. I'm staring the rows in the face and php is telling me that no such rows exist.